# Using React forwardRef with Redux connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a React functional component that is using `forwardRef` like this:

```
const wrapper = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <MyComponent {...props} innerRef={ref} />
));

export default wrapper;
```

Now I want to pass some state to this component using `mapStateToProps` with Redux's `connect` function like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MyComponent);
```

I tried to combine them in the following way but it didn't work:

```
const wrapper = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <MyComponent {...props} innerRef={ref} />
));

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(wrapper);
```

How do I combine these two to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 35):

You can use [options](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object) in connect function.

```
connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(wrapper)
```

Comment: I tried `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(MyComponent)`, but it didn't work. The issue is that it can't find the `innerRef` prop. How do I pass props with `connect`?

Comment: How do I use it in the class component? Any snippet, please?

Comment: if anyone is on react-redux version <= v6.0, they should use withRef in place of forwardRef.

Comment: @darKnight, I cannot get ref value. Ref value is always null.  Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the option on the connection method in redux: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

So the options allow use *forwardRef*

my code:  `connect(null,null,null,{forwardRef: true,})(LearnView)`

 it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

## If MyComponent is a functional component use hooks

This means that you don't need to write the connect wrapper at all. You can use hooks for redux is you're using a functional component.

```
const result : any = useSelector(selector : Function, equalityFn? : Function)
```

and

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

Comment: `MyComponent` is a class based component