# React forwardRef is never defined, even after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-forwardref

**EDIT: This problem was caused because I was attempting to use forwardRef in conjunction with Redux connect. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600130/using-react-forwardref-with-redux-connect) for the solution.**

I am attempting to access a DOM element in a parent component by using React.forwardRef. The problem is that ref.current never gets defined, even after the first render.

In this parent component, I want to access a DOM element from one of the child components:

```
const MyFunctionComponent = () => {
  const bannerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  let bannerIndent = useRef<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    // bannerRef.current is ALWAYS null. Why?
    if (bannerRef.current) {
    // this conditional block never runs, so bannerIndent is never defined
      const bannerWidth = bannerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      bannerIndent.current = `${bannerWidth}px`;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Banner ref={bannerRef} />
      <ComponentTwo bannerIndent={bannerIndent.current} />
    </>
  )
}
```

The component which receives the forwarded ref:

```
const Banner = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props> ((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} />
));
```

The component which needs some data derived from the forwarded ref:

```
const ComponentTwo = (props: {bannerIndent?: string}) => (
  <StyledDiv bannerIndent={props.bannerIndent} />
)

// styled.div is a styled-component
const StyledDiv = styled.div<{bannerIndent?: string}>`
  ... // styles, some of which depend on bannerIndent
`
```

Answers to existing SO questions which discuss forwardRef always being null or undefined point out that the ref will only be defined after the first render. I don't think that's the issue here, since the useEffect should run after the first render, yet bannerRef.current is still null.

The logic for setting the value of bannerIndent with a useEffect hook works correctly *if used inside of the Banner component with a normal ref*. However, I need to put the ref in the parent component so that bannerWidth (generated using the forwarded ref) can be passed to a sibling of the Banner component.

Help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: I am not sure by for me `bannerRef` is not showing null. Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-framework-ryh34?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hmm... Well, I did simplify my code quite a bit when posting. I must be doing something wrong my actual code.

Comment: When distilling your code down to a *runnable*, *reproducible* demo/example you will often find your issue, but the key words here are *runnable* and *reproducible*. If you share only a simplified version of your code be sure it still reproduces your issue.

Comment: Yes it would always great. If you create sandbox. It will help you explaining better and other will know what exactly have to debug

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese. I have posted the original code, not sure if that's too much to ask others to look at. Yes, *facepalm* I should have checked to make sure it reproduced the issue.

Comment: and thank you @ShubhamVerma - the problem is still cropping up, perhaps it has something to do with the fact that the Banner component is being imported into the parent component?